# Meaning of 人同士 in these sentences

Tags: meaning, words

I often hear "ひとどうし" in casual conversation, and I am never sure of its exact meaning.

I am not talking about 恋人同士, 大人同士, 日本人同士, 他人同士, etc.

Surprisingly, 人同士 is not in [my dictionary](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BA%BA%E5%90%8C%E5%A3%AB) nor [ALC](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BA%BA%E5%90%8C%E5%A3%AB), almost no examples show up on the web, so I am starting to believe that "ひとどうし" might be only the product of my imagination. I only found those examples:

A:

> そこでは、仮設住宅での状況とは逆に、知らない**人同士**が場所を共有し、対戦して楽しんでいます。

B:

> 外国籍市民を取り巻く友好の輪が広がり、様々な 文化背景を持つ**人同士**仲良く暮らせるように本書が活用されますこ とをお祈り申し上げます。

C:

> 比較的同じ世代の人達といっても、社会人と学生、フリーターや学校、仕事など、生活リズムが全く異なる**人同士**が一緒に暮らす訳ですから、同じ住居人のライフスタイルはある程度理解し合う姿勢が求められると思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because 知らない人同士 is `知らない人 + 同士` rather than `知らない + 人同士`. 同士 is a word that can be attached to any noun that represents a person (or sometimes an object). There is no grammatical difference between 恋人同士, 友達同士, 先生同士, 似た者同士 and 知らない人同士.